# Calling component controller through VF page by passing id as parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, code-coverage

I have to write a test class for a controller . It is a component's controller. The component is called in a VF page in below fashion

```
<apex:page standardController="Obj1__c"    extensions="ControllerForVFPage" id="apppage" standardStylesheets="false">

<c:AttachmentComp rendered="{!isActive}" ></c:AttachmentComp>
```

Now the component is as below

```
<apex:component controller="controllerForComponent" allowDML="true" access="global" >
```

Controller code for component

```
public class controllerForComponent{
  public controllerForComponent(){
        ObjId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        Page = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('PageName');
    }
```

What is the possible way of passing object id in the components controller test class .

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two options

**Option 1**

In the test method, do:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(new PageReference('/foo');
ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters().put('id',myMockedObjectId);
```

**Option 2 (preferred, decouples component from page where invoked)**

Change the signature of the component to not be dependent on page parameters

```
<apex:component AttachmentComp>
  <apex:attribute type="id" name="myObjId" required="true" assignto="{!theObjId}"/>
  ...
</apex:component>
```

Add a property in the componentController ...

```
public Id theObjId {get; set;}  // instantiated by assignTo attribute in component
```

and reference in the page as follows

```
<c:AttachmentComp myObjId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" ../>
```

Now your testmethod merely needs to do:

see [$CurrentPage VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm?search_text=$Page)

```
controllerForComponent ctrl = new controllerForComponent();
ctrl.theObjId = myMockedObjectId;
```